# What is default password for linksys WRT54GL routers? How to modify it?

Tags: passwords

What is default password for this user? Is there a way to modify default password so it does not reset when it is rebooted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Leave the username blank, and the password is admin. If you set that, it will hold it automatically, unless you use the reset button to set it back to the factory defaults (not something you can do by accident since you have to hold the button in for 5 seconds).

http://belkashop.com.ua/products_files/WRT54GL_V11_UG_EN.pdf

Comment: Sweet, they just hacked their neighbors wifi! ;->

Comment: lol :) just going to btjunkie.com...

Comment: Moab, if that is all it took, I don't feel too bad.

Comment: Which is exactly why you should always change the default password on a wireless router.

Comment: Since the user manuals are online for easy access in case you either lost the disk or misplaced it, searching for the manual is always my first choice if I need this information. +1 for Moab as a direct point being made, it's only hacking if you don't own the device but not changing default passwords on Wireless is like twittering you have a bag of gold on the dining room table at 123 anywhere street, sometown, somestate, USA, the door's unlocked and you won't be back in two weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
user:admin 
pw:password
```

Comment: This answer is not helpful as it is only a guess, and it is the wrong answer

Answer (score 0):

Leave the username blank, and the password is admin. 
If you set that, it will hold it automatically.
If not, use the reset button to set it back to the factory defaults:

Uplug power from the router 
Press & hold the reset button 
Plug in the router and do not let go of the button. Even if you let go for a split second, it will not work. 
Watch the lights.. Your router will boot up and the wlan light will come on after a bit. When the wlan light lights, your router is booted. If you keep holding the button, you will see the router boot again. The power light will blink, the wlan light will go off.

Once you see the blinking power light & the wlan light go off, release the reset button. Once the wlan light comes back on, your router is booted and will be set to defaults (assuming your button is functioning).

After that use login: root and pass: admin